# Looking for a new lightweight php editor for windows

Tags: php

Whats the most lightweight php editor out there for windows? other than notepad++

not looking for anything extreme,im just a 'hobby coder'

been using notepad++ for 3 years and im just getting tired of it, want some new

And what does it mean that a editor has "auto completing"?

thanks a lot!

Comment: When you type a function name, variable or something the editor prompt you for the completion. Much like predictave text on your old mobile phone.

Comment: Please add more information about the features you are looking for in the editor.

Comment: I think I've been using vim (and before that, vi) for 25 years. Not tired of it yet!

Comment: "best" and "lightweight" are both highly subjective concepts. You can't expect a reasonable answer to this question.

Answer (score 9):

[Sublime Text Editor](http://www.sublimetext.com/)

[image: Sublime Text Editor]

Comment: I love that Sublime is available on Mac, Windows and Linux, so I don't have to learn a different editor for each.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend vim ;)

However, as you didn't state what you wanted from an editor, have you looked at [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_editors)

Comment: After you learn Vim there's no going back. It is simply so much more powerful than any other editor around. This probably also applies to Emacs, though personally would prefer Vim as I found it easier to learn and somehow more intuitive to use.

Answer (score 2):

I like [SciTE](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html), which has highlighting for PHP and many other languages.

Answer (score 1):

[E Text Editor](http://www.e-texteditor.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [crimson editor](http://www.crimsoneditor.com/) for simple text editing and my first editor for stuff on PHP. It is definitely lightweight IMO although i don't think it is as powerful as Notepad++ and it is a bit outdated as its last release was in May 2008 but i still use it for simple stuff mainly because it is starts quickly as compared to the IDEs i use.

Auto-Completion is a feature in text editors which the text editor drops some hints to the variables/function names when you start to type. Very much like in browsers when you want to type in the address and it gives you the list of addresses in the history that matches whatever you have typed.

Answer (score 1):

[Geany](http://geany.org) does the job for me in Windows and Linux. And I also like [InType](http://intype.info/home/index.php), although I believe that its abandoned already.

Answer (score 0):

I used [UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com/) for several years, before i switched to [gvim](http://www.vim.org)
They are both excellent lightweight editors.

Although vim or emacs have steep learning curves and are not for everyone.

As far as heavyweight editors goes be sure to check out [eclipse with pdt](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/)